# How to show woocommerce shopping cart with php but customize it by adding an icon and changing the text

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

please help me, I want to show a woocommerce shopping cart with customized text and icon on my wordpress website. I am using this source code for reference: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/show-cart-contents-total/

I am showing it on the frontend, it looks like this with the source code from the link above, but I would like to show it with a  icon inside the  and I would also like to change the text, to be 'products' instead of 'items'

[image]

Here is my code of trying to show that icon and the changed text, please help me:

```
<a class="cart-customlocation" href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>">
<?php echo sprintf ( _n( '<i class="fa fa-cart"></i>Cart  %d product', '<i class="fa fa-cart"></i>Cart  %d products s', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?> - <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
```

Code in functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment' 
 );

function woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
global $woocommerce;

ob_start();

?>
<a class="cart-customlocation" href="<?php echo esc_url(wc_get_cart_url()); ?>" title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart', 'woothemes'); ?>"><?php echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> - <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
<?php
$fragments['a.cart-customlocation'] = ob_get_clean();
return $fragments; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Here's a quick example of the markup. You'll need to style with css.

html/php

```
<a href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>" class="basketicon" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>">
    <span class="basketicon__icon"></span>
    <span class="basketicon__total">
        <?php echo sprintf ( _n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?> - <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?>
    </span>
</a>
```

css/sass

```
.basketicon{
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
    padding: 0 30px 0 0;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;

    @media (min-width: $lg){
        margin: 0 30px 0 0;
        padding: 0 30px 0 0;
    }

    &::before{
        @media (min-width: $lg){
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            right: -10px;
            width: 20px;
            height: 1px;
            background: #fff;
        }
    }
    &__icon{
        &::before{
            content: url(../images/basket.svg);
            height: 10px;
            width: 10px;
            display: block;
        }
    }
    &__total{
        display: none;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: rem(16);
        margin: 0 0 0 10px;

        @media (min-width: $lg){
            font-size: rem(12);
            display: inline-block;
        }
        @media (min-width: $xl){
            font-size: rem(14);
        }
        @media (min-width: $xxxl){
            font-size: rem(15);
        }
    }
    &:hover,
    &:focus{
        .basketicon{
            &__icon{
                &::before{
                    transform: scale(0.8);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I still can't get the icon to appear, only the text appears, I am using your code, please help me.

Comment: ive changed the pseudo element to include a svg or png. As mentioned i've used icomoon for icons. if this isnt something you're using. you'll need to find a basket image, either png or svg

Comment: Hello, thank you a lot for the help, my theme didn't have a font awesome cdn for the stylesheet, plus I did not write the class for the icon properly. Here is simply what works


<a class="basketicon" href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>">
<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>

<?php echo sprintf ( _n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?> - <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>

Your code works perfectly too, thank you so much!